# Web Service Versioning

Tags: wcf, web-services, versioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices for versioning your services with WCF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36999/best-practices-for-versioning-your-services-with-wcf)

Alright so this has been my weak point and really do not know how to approach this. I have designed a WCF Web Service and cannot figure out what the best way to version (that is if I am using the correct word for it) the application so when changes are made for one client I dont have to have all others update and recompile their apps until they actually want changes made than they will get the new version that others might be using. I was hoping to eliminate client specific service. The web service references a common library for business layer. I don't know if I should follow a specific standard or doing this completely wrong, so I hope you can help me out or point me into right direction of the best way to do web service versioning.

Comment: Here is an awesome post about [Versioning Windows Communication Foundation Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigmcmurtry/archive/2006/07/23/676104.aspx). Also, i just did a demo for a colleague and posted it on [github](https://github.com/bchristie/PdfWriterService). It's very basic, but shows a little about versioning (ignore my project name (and other) typos, I was rushing through it during a meeting).

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wcf+versioning

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common and useful (from my point of view) ways to version your WS is by putting the version number in the URL according to each release.

For example, this is the url for the Twitter API

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/
```

So one of the functions are hosted here

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json
```

In case you need to update it and work in a new release, you can publish it here:

```
https://api.twitter.com/2.0/statuses/mentions_timeline.json
```

Let me know if that helps you somehow.

Regards,